# webservice call not firing functions

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have an asp.net 4.0 web service.  Inside that webserivce is a webmothod called Applicant.  When I hit the webservice.applicant webmothod by going to it through a web browser and hitting the asmx and typing in the parm names, everything runs like it should.  However, when I hit the webservice through another application part of the webmethod runs, part of it doesn't.

```
<WebMethod(True)> _
Public Function Applicant(pPassKey As String, pAgencyID As Integer, pFirstName As String, pLastName As String, pMI As String, pSSN As String, pID As String, pBirthdate As DateTime, pAddress1 As String, pAddress2 As String, pCity As String, pState As String, pZip As String, pEmail As String, pHPhone As String, pWPhone As String, pCPhone As String, pVeteransPreference As Integer, pDD214 As DateTime, pComments As String) As Integer
    'to test this use C:\Dev\PreDevelopment\WSDocd\Try1\Try1  solution

    Dempsey.fn.LogElmah("Test Logging")
    Dempsey.fn.TrackVisitInWebService() 'need to have this to make an entry about the session getting logged
    Try
```

So for example, when I call the webmethod from the website itself by going to the asmx page and then clicking on Applicant, everything fires.  When I just use the webservice from another application, the stuff inside the try runs, but the Dempsey.fn.TrackVisit.... does not run.  The LogElmah was just an attempt to write it out to the elmah log that it saw the line.  The elmah doesn't log anything when hitting it from another app but runs fine when running it from the asmx page.

There are also no errors logged in the try.  Does anyone have any ideas.
Hope I explained that ok
Thanks
shannon

Comment: What you've described seems to prove that the problem is not here in this code but in `Dempsey.fn` code.

Answer (score 0):

Well... as is too often the case.. error was on my end.. buried deep in the code was a all out to a stored proc.  In the stored proc was an insert into a table that has a column with a smallint data type.  Had reached the max value that could go in there so the sp would not fire and I didn't have the code there to report the error... anyway... it is what it is.
thanks
shannon